# How can I convert a string of "string appending equation" to the actual string appending equation?

Tags: c#, string, equation, evaluate

I am quite new to the C#, and I am trying to make my own scripting language that's going to be dynamically run. Now I have a problem converting/parsing a string of "string appending equation" to an actual equation.

Now, I know how to process a numeric math equation using DataTable, but this doesn't seem to process a string appending equations.

```cs
//This works just fine.
//Expected Value : 2.5
string mathEquation = "1+((2*3)/4)";
float mathAnswer = Convert.ChangeType(new System.Data.DataTable().Compute(mathEquation, ""),typeof(float));

//Error
//Expected Value : "Hello, world!"
string stringEquation = "\"Hello,\" + \" world!\"";
string stringAnswer = Convert.ChangeType(new System.Data.DataTable().Compute(stringEquation , ""),typeof(string));
```

So, I could just build a whole logic that just loops through letter by letter and separates them by strings and number and adds them up at the end, however, I just wonder if there's any API that supports this functionality.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is an xy problem - where do these strings come from?

Comment: *`I am trying to make my own scripting language`* You're going to need to write your own parser. You can't just convert arbitrary strings to C# code at runtime (at least, not easily and not a good idea). [For example](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), my own esolang interpreter.

Comment: That's really a rape of DataTable.Compute; but what error do you get ?
You nested Compute und ChangeType, which one fails with what exception ?
But however, you cannot base any scripting language on that, this is only constant expression evaluation.